# Ubuntu Server 20.04 Connected to WIFI but network no available

Tags: networking, network-manager

I am having a serious issue for a while now, and I haven't been able to fix it, I can't find a proper solution. I am using a Raspberry PI 4 with Ubuntu Server 20.04 and installed ubuntu desktop. Right now I have Wifi access, but when I try to connect to another wifi network it says "Wifi Unavailable" and the Visible Networks panel loads indefinitely without finding any network. Also, when I choose the select network option it says "No networks"

The first time a installed the OS I set the necessary configuration in /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

```
network:
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  version: 2
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      optional: true
      access-points:
        "home network":
           password: "password"
```

Then, I used these commands:

```
sudo netplan apply
sudo reboot
```

It seemed everything was fine, right now I have wifi access and can ping without any issues at all. The problem is that some commands show me that the wlan0 device is not working. When I use:

```
journalctl -e | grep NetworkManager
```

I get:

```
<error> [1632057111.4048] sup-iface[0xaaaae2bf5cd0,wlan0]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
<info>  [1632057121.3969] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
<info>  [1632057121.3971] device (wlan0): supplicant interface keeps failing, giving up
```

Also If I use:

```
nmcli d
```

I get:

```
wlan0 wifi unavailable
```

If I try to create a hotspot for the raspberry it says that wlan0 is unavailable, but I don't understand that since I am already connected and have wifi access!

Any ideas of what I can do?

**EDIT 1:**
I tried changing the renderer to NetworkManager but this didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using a Raspberry PI 4 with Ubuntu Server 20.04 and installed
> ubuntu desktop.

Servers usually use netplan to manage networking. Desktop installs use Network Manager. You have netplan all set up nicely but want Network Manager to work properly.

I suggest that you amend your netplan file to:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

You should now be able to select and connect to any network at the NM icon at the top right of your desktop: https://nfgk.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/network-manager.jpg?w=540

Comment: I did what you told me but still I have the same issue. When using sudo service NetworkManager status I got:
<error> [1632057111.4048] sup-iface[0xaaaae2bf5cd0,wlan0]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
<info>  [1632057121.3969] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
<info>  [1632057121.3971] device (wlan0): supplicant interface keeps failing, giving up

Comment: Is *wpa-supplicant* installed? Please show us: `sudo dpkg -s wpasupplicant | grep Status` and also: `sudo dpkg -s net-tools | grep Status`

Comment: I managed to fixed it, it was an issue with wpasupplicant, I used sudo service wpasupplicant status and the error said I needed to remove a file.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.